# How to focus and begin edit first cell of first row on page load of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to focus and begin edit first cell of first row when `UserControl` load or page load automatically. I've tried many code but wont find solution yet.I've write code for `DataGrid`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Inventory_Control.UserControls.FileTab"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Inventory_Control.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid Background="#FF2C2929">
        <DataGrid  DataGridCell.Selected="DataGrid_GotFocus" SelectionUnit="Cell" 
                   SelectionMode="Single" Name="Datagrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   PreviewKeyDown="Datagrid_PreviewKeyDown" 
                   CurrentCellChanged="Datagrid_CurrentCellChanged">

            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Code}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Code" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and on Constructor i've write code.

```
public FileTab()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AddValues();


    var grid = Datagrid;
    var cell = new DataGridCellInfo(0, grid.Columns[0]);
    grid.CurrentCell = cell;
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        grid.BeginEdit();
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get a reference to the cell to be focused. Wait until the elements have been loaded and then use the `VisualTreeHelper` class:

```
public FileTab()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AddValues();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        DataGrid grid = dg;
        DataGridRow rowContainer = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as DataGridRow;
        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);
            if (presenter != null)
            {
                DataGridCell cell = presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as DataGridCell;
                if (cell != null)
                {
                    DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo = new DataGridCellInfo(cell);
                    if (!grid.SelectedCells.Contains(dataGridCellInfo))
                    {
                        grid.SelectedCells.Add(dataGridCellInfo);
                    }
                    grid.CurrentCell = dataGridCellInfo;
                    grid.BeginEdit();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```